# Fix: Use global instead of window

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, runkit

I am trying a component inside runkit.com. As it is visible from the image, the platform tells me ...

> Fix: Use global instead of window.
>   RunKit is a node environment, so window and other browser features won’t exist. If you’re just trying to access the global object, you can simply use global instead.

This is the code pasted:

```
var window = {};
const QueryQl = require("queryfilters/queryql")
var q = new QueryQl();
q.json({
    'ciao': 'mondo'
});
q.getQueryString();
```

[image: Fix: Use global instead of window.]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You cant without editing the module

Comment: `global.module = global.module || {}` works!!

Comment: @JonasW. As the error is a ReferenceError defining window may be the solution, Without needing for editing the module.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is simple. Just replace this

```
window.module = window.module || {};
```

with this:

```
global.module = global.module || {};
```

in the module.

Comment: With every update to the module you will have to replace it again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to define window to the global, Before calling the module:

```
global.window = {}
```